# What is best practice to log4cxx？

Tags: c++, logging

I try to write log message to disk, so I choose FileAppender(sync no buffer). But the speed not so good.
consider following code

```
const std::string pattern("%d %m%n");
log4cxx::LayoutPtr layPtr = new PatternLayout(pattern);
FileAppender *fileappender = new FileAppender(layPtr, "log4cxx_bench.log", true);
const std::string line(30, 'k');
LOG4CXX_INFO(logger1, line);
```

spend almost 4 seconds. file size is 60MB. so the speed is 15MB/s。I try to profile with Xcode, The profile image is below:
[image]

change to sync with buffer. almost same. I don't know how to optimize it.

Answer (score 1):

In short: log less by default.

Most of your LOG4CXX calls should be at a level that is not logged by default in a production system. When something goes wrong and you want to debug some component of your system, you adjust the configuration such that for that component logging is done at a more verbose level. This is to speedup your application by logging less.

Another idea is to configure your LOG4CXX such that for each log message, less additional information is printed (if you don't need them).

Alternatively, you could change the log file to use a faster device, such as a flash SSD or even tmpfs.